# Wie kriegt man die Ente wieder weg?

Tags: discussion

Mir ist gerade aufgefallen, dass auf German Language rechts unten eine gelbe Ente hockt:

[image]

Wenn man draufklickt wird man nach einem Mikrophon gefragt:

[image]

Wenn man hier auf "No" (!) klickt, schaltet sich das Mikrophon ein!

[image]

Erste Frage:
Warum ignoriert dieses blöde Vieh meine Angabe?

Zweite (weitaus wichtigere Frage):
**Wie kriege ich diese unnütze Ente wieder weg?**

---

Ich will, dass dieses Ding wieder verschwindet, und zwar möglichst sofort!

Wenn es sich schon nach dem Mikrofon erkundigt, dann soll es mich nicht fragen ob ich eines habe, sondern ob es es einschalten darf.

Wenn ich einem Programm nicht ausdrücklich erlaube, auf das Mikrofon oder die Kamera (oder auf sonstige Geräte) zuzugreifen, darf so ein Zugriff nicht erfolgen! Ich habe diese Erlaubnis nicht erteilt, trotzdem kam es zu einem Zugriff!

Comment: Please do not tag this a `bug` - it isn't. Bug tags cause a lot of noise in the network.

Comment: I wouldn't blame Hubert here for tagging something a bug that looks like a bug.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1348/revisions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue went away and is unlikely to come back - no more quack overflow.

Comment: When it looks like a bug and walks like a bug and quacks like a bug ... probably it is a bug ;) .

Comment: Unter der Bedingung den Thread von den spielverderberischen Verraten zu säubern plädiere ich für reopen - das nächste Jahr kommt bestimmt bald, es wird auch schon wieder kälter.

Comment: Die Behauptung *»This question does not appear to be about ... the software that powers the Stack Exchange network«* ist schlichtweg falsch. Diese Ente ist Stack-Exchange-Software, daher trifft der vorgeschobene Schließungsgrund nicht zu.

Comment: Es gibt absolut keinen vernünftigen Grund, weshalb sich genau dieser Aprilscherz wiederholen sollte. Nachdem die Ente mittlerweile auch im letzten Cache verschwunden sein dürfte, kann man die gestellte Frage nicht mehr vernünftig beantworten. Wenn Ihr eine neue Frage über den Sinn und Unsinn von Aprilscherzen auf S.E. stellen möchtet: [ask]. Die Ente ist aber definitiv Schnee von vorgestern!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: hier findet ihr den Schließgrund: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/wie-kriegt-man-die-ente-wieder-weg#comment3155_1348 - da ist wie immer nix vorgeschoben. Es gibt halt einfach nur keinen vorgefertigten Schließgrund: *Suprise, surprise, april-fool went away all on its own just after a day*.

Answer (score 3):

Nur zur Klarstellung:

## Die Ente greift *nicht* auf das Mikrofon zu.

Kann sie auch gar nicht ohne explizite Genehmigung des Nutzers (zumindest in jedem vernünftigen Browser). Das Verhalten der Ente ist immer dasselbe. Das Schlimmste, was passieren kann, ist, dass man plötzlich Gespräche mit seinem Rechner führt, die Mitmenschen an der eigenen geistigen Gesundheit zweifeln lassen.

Bedenke: Wenn die Ente ohne Berechtigung auf das Mikrofon zugreifen könnte, könnten das auch alle anderen Internetseiten (mit ähnlichen Berechtigungen).

Comment: *»Kann sie auch gar nicht ohne explizite Genehmigung des Nutzers«* sagt die Theorie, in der Praxis ist das aber falsch. Ich absolviere derzeit den Masterstudiengang *Information Security* an der FH St. Pölten, und da haben wir im Zuge der Lehrveranstaltung *Penetration Testing* in einem Experiment dargestellt, dass es unter bestimmten Voraussetzungen möglich ist, via Internet die Kamera eines Windows-PCs in Betrieb zu nehmen, ohne dass der Anwender das mitbekommt, und ohne Spuren auf dem angegriffenen Computer zu hinterlassen. Und wenn das mit der Kamera geht, geht das auch mit dem Mikrofon.

Comment: Meine Aussagen gelten weiterhin: Wenn die Ente so einfach auf Dein Mikrofon zugreifen könnte, könnten das auch alle anderen Webseiten. Dann wäre Dein Browser eine große Sicherheitslücke (und nicht vernünftig).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast wieso sollte ein Aprilscherz auf Dein Mikrofon zugreifen? Das macht gar keinen Sinn.

Comment: @Takkat: Das macht durchaus Sinn: Der Aprilscherz könnte die Tarnung eines Hackers sein.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das Argument *»Wenn die Ente so einfach auf Dein Mikrofon zugreifen könnte, könnten das auch alle anderen Webseiten.«* ist ja keineswegs ein Beweis dafür, dass es nicht geht. Wie schon in meinem ersten Kommentar dargelegt, geht genau das unter bestimmten Bedingungen. Auch Browser können große Sicherheitslücken haben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: da hast Du völlig Recht - natürlich können Hackerangriffe Dein Mikrophon anschalten und in das Internet streamen. Wir müssen da alle sehr besorgt sein und Vorkehrungen treffen. Tip: an meinem Computer hängt gar kein Mikrophon dran - solche Hardware-Hürden sind auch für den besten Hacker unüberwindbar!